# What is the meaning of this symbol

Tags: convolution

Could you please explain or give some resources about the [symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kkk2.png) "line" on the head of the function

Comment: Depending on the context, it could mean almost anything. Try to find it in the book, surely they explain it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the symbol of **conjugation** meaning here that the matrix of inverse Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is (up to a multiplicative constant) the conjugate of the direct DFT matrix.

See for example [this](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Matrix_Formulation_DFT.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help